# Cannot work out what is using port 8080

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, tcp

In Windows Server 2003 R2 64 Bit SP2 I have an app which will only use port 8080 but something is already using it. I would be happy to just kill whatever is using it but I can't work out what it is. I have run TCPView and it showed a PID of 3216 with a process of "". I have tried taskkill /pid 3216 but it says:

> ERROR: The process "3216" not found."

If I browse to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` I get one of the errors below, so it looks a bit like a webserver of some sort. If I try to kill the process in TCPView nothing happens. Can anyone make any other suggestions?

> Forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Internal Server Error. The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please
> contact the server administrator, admin@example.com and inform them of
> the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may
> have caused the error. More information about this error may be
> available in the server error log.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `netstat -ba` in administrator level command prompt, and you will see all active network sockets and processes that own those sockets.

- `-b` tells netstat to output executable name of the socket owner.
- `-a` tella netstat to list all listening and client sockets.

Answer (score 3):

This is what i did in windows 8:

run resmon

In Network Tab click on listening port, here we could see all the ports which is currently being used.

Comment: Nice GUI answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Port 8080 is a fairly commonly used port for Java apps. Either via Tomcat or Jetty.  My bet would be Tomcat. Since this is a server & you clearly cannot access the content on port 8080, then my suggestion would be to look through your process list for anything Java related. Possibly also check the contents on ports 8081 as well as port 8000.

Answer (score 1):

Check is IIS is running. IIS uses kernel-level driver (http.sys) to handle http requests, so it's not displayed correctly in netstat.

If it's there, check what site binds to :8080.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers here I ended up being able to find out it was Apache by following these steps in a windows command prompt:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
GET / HTTP/1.1<cr>
<cr>
```

Where <cr> = enter key

That produced a response which showed the headers and one of the headers gave away it was Apache. I found a httpd process running that I could kill. This wasn't something I was looking for because Apache is not installed but something had run a stand alone Apache instance (I checked it wasn't a virus).